# Is there a way to make an SFTP connection to a remote machine through jump server to transfer files?

Tags: ssh, sftp, sendfile

I was wondering if there's a way to send files using SFTP to a remote machine through a jump server.
As you can see in the image below first it's needed an SSH connection and after that an SFTP connection.

[image]

My main problem here comes after the SSH connection, my workspace has changed and I cannot retrieve the necessary files to execute the SFTP successfully.
I've tried the following code:

```
ssh jump-server-user@ip-jump-server 'echo "put /source/files /remote/files" | sftp -v remote-machine-user@ip-remote-machine'
```

But it does not work.

I've tried to execute a simple command like `pwd` using the SFTP connection and it works so I think the problem here is how the workspace change.

There would probably be an easier solution but I cannot use SSH on the jump server-remote machine connection and I cannot store the local files in the jump server to send them later to the remote machine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have a recent OpenSSH (at least 8.0) *locally*, you can use the [`-J` (jump) switch](https://man.openbsd.org/scp#J):

```
sftp -J jump-server-user@ip-jump-server remote-machine-user@ip-remote-machine
```

With older version  (but at least 7.3), you can use [`ProxyJump` directive](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config#ProxyJump):

```
sftp -o ProxyJump=jump-server-user@ip-jump-server remote-machine-user@ip-remote-machine
```

---

There are other options like `ProxyCommand` or port forwarding, which you can use on even older versions of OpenSSH. These are covered in [Does OpenSSH support multihop login?](https://superuser.com/q/1488097/213663)

Comment: I have a higher version of OpenSSH 8.0 and the first option worked for me so thank you so much!